# One-To-Many relationship with navigation property only on one side?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

I have perfectly fine one-to-many relationship between two tables: `Play` and `Player`:

```
public class Player
{
    public int PlayerId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Play> Plays { get; set; }
}

public class Play
{
    public int PlayId { get; set; }

    public int PlayerId { get; set; }
    public Player Player { get; set; }
}

modelBuilder.Entity<Play>()
    .HasOne<Player>(p => p.Player)
    .WithMany(p => p.Plays)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
    .HasForeignKey(p => p.PlayerId)
    .IsRequired();
```

Is it possible to omit navigation property on side? For example remove `Plays` collection from `Player`?

```
public class Player
{
    public int PlayerId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I'm gonna have two specific questions:

1. Is it possible to do it at all?
2. Is it possible to do it, without relying on EF Core conventions - e.g. "Id" is a primary key etc...? (Meaning, having everything explicit, either in fluent API or as Annotations)

Comment: I know that EF Core has a few conventions, so that you don't have to write any code in fluent API. Like for property `Id` EFCore will create PK, without Annotations or FluentAPI. I didn't want to get an answer like "You don't have to do it, because EFCore will interpret this using its conventions automatically"

Comment: @TanvirArjel but it looks like your answer is the one I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to omit navigation property on side? For example remove `Plays` collection from `Player`?

Absolutely possible. Write you entity configuration as follows:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Play>()
    .HasOne<Player>(p => p.Player)
    .WithMany() // <-- Here it is
    .HasForeignKey(p => p.PlayerId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
    .IsRequired();
```

> Is it possible to do it, without relying on EF Core conventions - e.g. "Id" is a primary key etc...? (Meaning, having everything explicit, either in fluent API or as Annotations)

No! Its not possible without *Fluent API*.