# How to configure one-to-many relationship with navigation property only on one side (on collection side) with EF Core 5?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Lets say we have `Airport` and `Runway` classes:
have perfectly fine one-to-many relationship between two tables: Play and Player:

```
public class Airport
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Runway> Runways { get; set; }
}

public class Runway
{
    public int Id { get; set; }    
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //public int AirportId { get; set; } <- I don't need it!!!
}
```

My goal is to omit navigation property on `Runway` side (I don't need a link to `Airport` here).

But when I use `dotnet-ef migrations add InitialCreate` command - an `AirportId` field is created in database for `Runway` table.
How to configure one-to-many relationship with navigation property only on one side (on collection side) with EF Core 5?

There is [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60312236/one-to-many-relationship-with-navigation-property-only-on-one-side) but for navigation property on a collection side.

I've tried the following with no success (nothing changes):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Airport>()
.HasMany<Runway>(a => a.Runways)
.WithOne()
.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
.IsRequired();
```

Comment: Was the airportId field in one of your initial migrations before you decided you were going to remove it? because I see no reason why the column would be included in your database if you never specified it.

Comment: In one-to-many, you need the foreign key in many side table. It's normal to have `AirportId` in `Runaway` table.

Comment: EF will create a nullable `AirportId` foreign key column in the `Runway` table even if you remove the  property and the relation configuration code. How do you expect the database to keep track of which `Runway` belongs to which `Airport` without a foreign key column? A foreign key column is the central concept of a one-to-many relationship.

Comment: @Qudus - no it wasn't. I have no previous migrations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A foreign key column is the central concept of having a functional one-to-many relationship. The database needs it to identify which child entity (`Runway`) belongs to which parent entity (`Airport`). Therefore, you cannot avoid it.

If you don't want the `AirportId` and the `Airport` reference in your `Runway` class you can safely remove them and use the models as -

```
public class Airport
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Runway> Runways { get; set; }
}

public class Runway
{
    public int Id { get; set; }    
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

You can even remove the relation configuration code as well. EF will automatically create a nullable foreign key column `AirportId` in the `Runway` table and use it as a `Shadow property` (which you cannot access) behind the scene to manage the relationship.

Comment: Looks like it's my fault. I have **existing** database that was created by EF 6.4. And I'm migrating my code to EF Core 5. I've expected that EF 6.4.4 didn't not created navigation property in the `Runway` table. In fact it **was** created but with different name - `Airport_Id`. So that is the problem with reading that navigation field from existing database and establishing a connection between tables by EF Core 5.

Comment: So I've ended with `builder.Entity<Airport>().HasMany(a => a.Runways) .WithOne().HasForeignKey("Airport_Id").OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade).IsRequired();`